# Save JMeter image from GUI mode programmatically

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In JMeter GUI mode it is possible to save image of specific element into image. For example here is [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=ThroughputShapingTimer), it is possible to save image with expected RPS from right-click on graph in the bottom:

[image: jp@gc - Throughput Shaping Timer]

Saving image into file is available for other plugin components (listeners, thread groups). Is it possible to somehow get such image from non-GUI mode?

**Edit**

Use case example:
Having expected RPS (exported from the element as shown above) and actual RPS (say, from generated "hits per second" report), compare application performance.

The problem is that numbers of expected RPS may be constantly changed, so updating image with expected RPS turns into boring repetitive task (every time open JMeter GUI, find element, saving image...).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the unattended way of generating the visual representation of the Throughput Shaping Timer however it's possible to generate the following charts as images from the .jtl results file:

- [Server Hits per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/)
- [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/)

in my opinion it will make more sense as you will plot the **perceived** load, not the anticipated load hence the image will represent actual test results.

If this is something you are interested in, the images can be generated via [JMeter Plugins Command Line Graph Plotting Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/) like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD --generate-png hits-per-second.png --input-jtl /path/to/your/result.jtl --plugin-type HitsPerSecond --width 1024--height 768
```

and

```
JMeterPluginsCMD --generate-png txh-per-second.png --input-jtl /path/to/your/result.jtl --plugin-type TransactionsPerSecond --width 1024--height 768
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware about generating graphs from existing .jtl results, but it is not the case from question.

The question is exactly about saving images from test plan elements in non-GUI way, so this step could be automated, e.g. in CI/CD.

Comment: Added my use case to post.